# How to avoid business logic breaking when parallel POST requests occur in Rest API

Tags: sql, .net, api, rest, concurrency

I am trying to make a REST application where I have entities of Users and Orders.

**Clarifying information:**

The order entity has status that can be: new, processing, completed.
When users add an order, its status will be set to new.
The user can only have 5 max 'new' orders, any other new order will be simply rejected.
I have multiple instances of the API in production.

*My question is*: What if a user did request a large number of requests to create orders, let's say: 100 requests. How can I handle these parallel requests in a way that will not break the rule limiting the user to have 5 max 'new' orders ?
What if these parallel requests passed the validation rule at the same time and then created 100 'new' orders?

Let's assume the tech stack is .NET and EF Core.

**Solutions I thought of:**

1.Pessemistic locking: But I am worried that locking will cause performance drawbacks.

2.Optimistic locking: Should I re-check the validation rule just before committing the transaction ? this doesn't seem a feasible solution. In other words, it cannot guarantee me a perfect solution.

Comment: Very simple - queue your orders. Then dequeue into the DB. The DQ process will have only one thread that saves to DB. And it can also direct any extra orders into rejection queue. Here you are!
In other words - any kind of **staging** - good. 
Even if this is not a real queue. You take the user request and say - your request received. Then you process it later at which time you either accept or reject

Comment: Hey @T.S.,
Thanks for your reply, but In this case we have to execute orders synchronously ?
Let's say that we have 10 users and 10 orders each, so I will add 50 orders to the queue, but then I execute them one by one ?

Comment: you can't control **WHEN** orders come in. But you can control **HOW** you process them when you process a queue.